# How to append text from bash to vim?

Tags: bash, vim, editor, subshell

I know about `r!` command to append text from bash output to vim under cursor. So for example issuing this command in vim:

```
:r! printf "abcd\n"
```

would append "abcd" into the vim buffer. But I am somehow unable to do similar with subshell involved. In file `a.sh`, I issue:

```
:r! printf "This file was created on %s" $(date +%m/%d/%y)
```

And the result is

```
This file was created on a.shs
```

some nonsense created from the filename. Why? (on normal terminal, there is no such problem, so I am assuming vim cannot handle subshells?)

Answer (score -1):

`:r! printf "This file was created on \%s" "$(date +\%m/\%d/\%y)"`

Comment: This command does print the string "This file was created on \" followed by the name of the current edited file.

pfrintf is not a command it's a function. Passing bash command retrurn values does not work as shown.

Comment: @zzeroo is also `/usr/bin/printf`

Comment: @BDL `%` is the name of current file, as @zzeroo mentioned. The `\%` just escapes it.  The `"$(date ...)"` means that the resulting stdout is given as a single parameter to `/usr/bin/printf` instead of more, like in "Fri" "Nov" "13" etc.